# Duvida no funcionamento de um codigo Python (Classes e objetos)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gente, não estou entendendo algo nesse codigo. Eu estou importando as classes Cliente e Conta em um outro programa para utiliza-las. Mas não consegui entender por que ele está funcionando, sendo que o método depósito é ''chamado'' uma vez antes dele ter sido sequer definido.

```
class Cliente:

    def __init__(self, nome, telefone):
        self.nome = nome
        self.telefone = telefone


class Conta:

    def __init__(self, clientes, numero, saldo = 0):
        self.saldo = saldo
        self.clientes = clientes
        self.numero = numero
        self.operacoes = []
        self.deposito(saldo)  # AQUI ELE SENDO UTILIZADO

    def resumo(self):
        print('CC Numero: %s Saldo: %10.2f'
              %(self.numero,self.saldo))

    def saque(self, valor):
        if self.saldo >= valor:
            self.saldo -= valor
        self.operacoes.append(['Saque', valor])

    def deposito(self, valor):  # SÓ AQUI ELE É DEFINIDO
        self.saldo += valor
        self.operacoes.append(['Deposito',valor])

    def extrato(self):
        for x in self.operacoes:
            print(x[0], x[1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que me parece você está fazendo confusão entre **declaração de função** e **chamada de função**.

No seu exemplo as funções estão sendo apenas **declaradas**. Elas não estão sendo chamadas à execução. Assim, não tem problema nenhum quanto à função depósito aparecer dentro de outra função um pouco mais acima, pois ela não é chamada, ou seja, não será executada.

Interprete isto como um índice de funções que o programa possui para fazer aquilo ao qual foi projetado. Simples assim.

Agora, quando a função `__init__` for executada, sim, neste caso todos os dados necessários, como **saldo, clientes, operação**, etc. deverão já ter sido definidos. Pela lógica, o sistema bancário fará a consulta dos dados necessários no momento do login do usuário, ou seja, qualquer função que for chamada a partir dali já estará plenamente suprida de dados necessários.